# How to print md5sum on separate line?

Tags: windows, command-line, md5sum

I am trying to calculate the md5 hash of a string (say 'hunter5'). To do this, I run `md5sum` , type or paste the string, then type Control-D (EOT) twice.

```
> md5sum
hunter5ef6ea1eaa2e851d5d855f7773fc150af *-
```

The hash is printed on the same line as the original string, which makes it frustrating to copy and paste. Is there a better way?

I have this problem both in Windows and Linux.

Comment: You are asking about the widows command line specifically? Or is this powershell?

Comment: You're seeing your input printed back followed by the md5 checksum. Do it as Colonel Panic did below, using an echo and pipe it to md5sum command.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash (Windows or Linux), this works

```
$ echo -n "hunter5" | md5sum
ef6ea1eaa2e851d5d855f7773fc150af *-
```

But beware! On cmd this gives the wrong answer

```
> echo "hunter5" | md5sum
466f34712f1c143c0a428275d714ad4c *-
```

Comment: This is not the _wrong_ answer. Have a look how `echo "hunter5"` is working in `cmd`: It prints the apostrophes, too! You also have to think about if newline `\n` or `\r\n` is included.

Comment: What Colonel Panic was trying to say is that you need to send it to the pipe without newlines, otherwise, on (this) command, it produces the wrong sum (answer).